# Workaroubnd for NGC / Nvidia GPU coud

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, nvidia

I wrote some tensorflow code in python 3.6. Now I want to run my code on a workstation that uses the Nvidia GPU cloud docker ([NGC](https://ngc.nvidia.com/)) to utilize the GPU.

Unfortunately the Nvidia docker only supports python 3.5. Thus the main error is the string formatting (f"{}"). Does anyone know a workaround for this problem or do I have to change every string formatting in my code?

And does anyone have other problems in mind, when I downgrade my code to 3.5?

Comment: You could backport `f` literals using a package `ww` ( pip install ww ). Theoretically this should have been available in the `__future__` module however 3.5 is in maintenance mode status, and you can't add new major features on an existing release branch.

Comment: Thanks, that works. You can post it as answer and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could backport f literals using a package ww ( `pip install ww` ). Theoretically this should have been available in the **future** module however 3.5 is in maintenance mode status, and you can't add new major features on an existing release branch.